# Is it possible to add Child View Controller using HERO animations in swift 4?

Tags: swift, animation

Currently, I am using following code to add a child view in my View Controller.

```
   self.selectTimeVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectTimeViewController") as! SelectTimeViewController
   self.addChildViewController(self.selectTimeVC
   self.view.addSubview(self.selectTimeVC.view)    
   self.didMove(toParentViewController: self.selectTimeVC)
```

Is it possible to add this view animately using Hero Animations? If not, Can you suggest any other code to do the same?

Comment: did you found any Solution?

Comment: not yet, But I will post it , once I have